# C# Abrir child de child y luego cerrarlos independientes

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios

Tengo un form principal que no es contenedor, desde este form abro otro con el siguiente código:

```
frmForm1 formulario1 = new frmForm1();
formulario1.ShowDialog();
```

Una vez abierto, este form tiene otro menú en el cual abro otro form de la siguiente manera:

```
frmForm2 formulario2 = new frmForm2();
formulario2.ShowDialog();
```

El problema viene cuando cierro este último form (formulario2) que se cierran los dos a la vez (el form2 y el form1), he probado de cualquier manera.
¿Alguein sabe que puedo hacer para cerrar primero el form 2, y luego si quiero, pues cerrar el form 1 ?
Todo ello con el form principal abierto.
salduos y gracias.

Comment: El problema es que los dos son dialog y no podes tener mas de 1 dialog al mismo tiempo... nos explicas que queres hacer bien?

Comment: Hola  gbianchi, gracias por contestar. Lo que quiero hacer es, tengo el form main que es un mantenimiento de clientes, de ahi le doy al boton imprimir (abre el form1), este form1 tiene la opcion de mandar el informe por impresora o por email, si le doy a email lanzo el form2 que contiene un textbox para poner un email y así  mandarlo. saludos.